# Donation to scientific institution that I own or belong to and its tax deduction

Tags: united-states, taxes, research

Being a researcher myself, I'm interested in donating to scientific institutions and enjoying some tax deduction. In particular, if I donate to my own lab group (or any non-profit scientific institution I  founded) to hire postdocs and purchase computation resources, is it tax deductible just like any non-profit scientific institution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your non-profit scientific institution is a [501(c)(3) organization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/501(c)(3)_organization), then yes, you can make tax deductible donations to it.

The caution, of course, is to make sure, as the administrator of a non-profit, that you do not misuse your organization's funds.